# How to query nested objects with multiple value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have array of nested objects in my MongoDB schema. Lets say,

```
var Post = {
    "title": "Some title",
    "advertisers" : [
        {
            "category" : "Tech",
            "name" : "Henry",
            "city" : "New york",
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2011-07-26T21:02:19Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2011-07-26T21:02:19Z")
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to find the post based on the multiple values in nested schema. eg

```
Post.find({ 'advertisers.category' : 'Tech', 'advertisers.city': 'New York' });
```

It returns post which matches one of the above criteria. But i want posts which matches both.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) operator to do this:

```
Post.find({ advertisers: {$elemMatch: {category: 'Tech', city: 'New York' }}})
```